# How to wrap appContainer with a theme provider tag from react-native-elements?

Tags: react-native, user-interface, react-navigation, react-native-elements

I need to enclose my app main component with a ThemeProvider tag, but I don't know where to enclose it, because I am using an appContainer from react-navigation, look like I need to enclose the appContainer instead.

I am working in a react-native project without expo. I am importing react-native-elements and react-navigation. I need to enclose my app.js which is already wrapped by an appContainer

App.js

```
import { createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import PantallaInicio from './components/home/PantallaInicio';
import PantallaLogin from './components/auth/PantallaLogin';
import PantallaRegistro from './components/auth/PantallaRegistro';
import PantallaCargando from './components/auth/PantallaCargando';

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: PantallaInicio, });
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ Login: PantallaLogin, Registro: PantallaRegistro });

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: PantallaCargando,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }

));
```

index.js

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Sorry, I don't have any output yet, Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createAppContainer` returns `React Component`. Thus, you can wrap this using any `provider`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'react-native-elements';
import theme from './your-theme';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

const ProvidedApp = () => {
  return <ThemeProvider theme={theme} ><App /></ThemeProvider>
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => ProvidedApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Im borrowing this thread a bit for a problem I am having regarding what Jeff Gu Kang said..

> Jeff Gu Kang: "You can use any ThemeProvider"

I am using `<ThemeProvider/>` from react-native-elements wrapping the component that createAppContainer returns. The theme prop is either a lightTheme och darkTheme object depending on the lightThemeState.

With `screenProps` I send down a function that a screen component can use to change theme from light to dark. But the screens doesnt update... If I change the state of `lightThemeNav` to false, everything changes and works fine but for some reason it doesnt update the theme when I toggle the button. (the button changes state correctly)

Here is the code:

```
const TabNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    FindDestinationScreen: {
      screen: FindDestinationScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Search",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <SafeAreaView>
            <Icon
              style={[{ color: tintColor }]}
              size={25}
              name={"ios-search"}
            />
          </SafeAreaView>
        ),
      },
    },
  },
  {
    barStyleDark: {
      backgroundColor: "#212121",
      shadowColor: "#000",
      shadowOffset: { width: 3, height: 2 },
      shadowOpacity: 0.8,
      shadowRadius: 2,
      elevation: 1,
    },
    barStyleLight: {
      backgroundColor: "#3c5e82",
    },
    shifting: false,
    labeled: true,
    initialRouteName: "FindDestinationScreen",
    activeColor: "#E4DC93",
    inactiveColor: "#fff",
    barStyle: { backgroundColor: "transparent", height: 80, paddingTop: 10 },
  }
);

const AllRoutes = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    PersonalSettings: {
      title: "Personal Settings",
      screen: PersonalSettings,
      header: ({ goBack }) => ({
        left: (
          <Icon
            name={"chevron-left"}
            onPress={() => {
              goBack();
            }}
          />
        ),
      }),
    },
    Tabs: {
      screen: TabNavigator,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Tabs",
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AllRoutes);

export default App = () => {
  const [lightThemeState, setLightThemeState] = useState(true);

  return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={lightThemeState ? lightTheme : darkTheme}>
        <AppContainer
          theme={lightThemeState ? "light" : "dark"}
          screenProps={{
            setLightThemeState: setLightThemeState,
          }}
        />
      </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

I also made a question in more detailed here.. 
[changing theme with react native elements not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61294890/changing-theme-with-react-native-elements-not-working)

Would be grateful for anykind of help.. Thanks!